# Virtualmin: "PHP execution via fcgid requires the Apache mod_fcgid module"

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid, mod-fastcgi

I have a CentOS server with Virtualmin on it. I have configured PHP the way I want it, using Apache mod_fastcgi. However, when I click "Re-check Config" in Virtualmin, I get

`PHP execution via fcgid requires the Apache mod_fcgid module`

[This post](http://www.virtualmin.com/node/9108) says to change `Default PHP execution mode` to `CGI`, but I can't find such an option anywhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I solved it by enabling `mod_fcgid` in Apache but just not configuring it. But that's wasting memory, and I'd love to know the "proper" way to solve this!

Comment: UG. This solution is causing all sorts of other issues with the newest version of Virtualmin...

Answer (score 1):

mod_fastcgi (www.fastcgi.com) is a 3rd-party module whose directives have a "FastCgi" prefix.

mod_fcgid http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html is an Apache module whose directives have a "Fcgid" prefix.

I advise that you remove mod_fastcgi and go with mod_fcgid.

That's great news for PHP, because then you can dump apache mpm-prefork and go with the better mpm-worker, by not installing mod_php, instead use php as fast cgi.  For debian, this means:

• Remove apache2-mpm-prefork and libapache2-mod-php5.

• Add apache2-mpm-worker, libapache2-mod-fcgid, and php5-cgi.  With php5-cgi, you don't need a custom fast cgi wrapper, you can use the php command-line itself directly (notice the /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5) below.

• For mod_fcgid with PHP, note that PHP as FastCGI has its own facility for terminating after handling so many requests (see PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS).  FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess helps avoid sending additional requests to the wrapper application after it has handled its limit.

• Inside each virtual host or at global scope:

```
    FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 200
    FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 200
```

• Then inside Directory:

```
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FcgidWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 .php
    Options +ExecCGI
```

Comment: I'm using Apache mpm_worker. The issue is that I want mod_fastcgi and Virtualmin wants mod_fcgid. I have FastCGI working perfectly and don't want to switch it. The question was, how can I make Virtualmin run without installing mod_fcgid?